# Bundler installing gems in wrong location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

This is kind of bizarre. Any time I do a bundle install, Bundler installs all my gems to the path #{RAILS_ROOT}/json_pure/ruby/1.8/gems. I copied the Gemfile directly from another application that works perfectly, and I don't think I've modified any other configuration. Any ideas what could be going on here?

Not sure if it helps, but my Gemfile.lock is below:

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    GData (0.0.4)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      hoe (>= 1.2.1)
    abstract (1.0.0)
    actionmailer (3.0.0.rc)
      actionpack (= 3.0.0.rc)
      mail (~> 2.2.5)
    actionpack (3.0.0.rc)
      activemodel (= 3.0.0.rc)
      activesupport (= 3.0.0.rc)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      erubis (~> 2.6.6)
      i18n (~> 0.4.1)
      rack (~> 1.2.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.6.9)
      rack-test (~> 0.5.4)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.22)
    activemodel (3.0.0.rc)
      activesupport (= 3.0.0.rc)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      i18n (~> 0.4.1)
    activerecord (3.0.0.rc)
      activemodel (= 3.0.0.rc)
      activesupport (= 3.0.0.rc)
      arel (~> 0.4.0)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.22)
    activeresource (3.0.0.rc)
      activemodel (= 3.0.0.rc)
      activesupport (= 3.0.0.rc)
    activesupport (3.0.0.rc)
    arel (0.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0.beta)
    bcrypt-ruby (2.1.2)
    builder (2.1.2)
    capybara (0.3.9)
      culerity (>= 0.2.4)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 0.0.3)
    chronic (0.2.3)
      hoe (>= 1.2.1)
    columnize (0.3.1)
    configuration (1.1.0)
    crummy (0.1.0)
    culerity (0.2.10)
    database_cleaner (0.5.2)
    devise (1.1.rc2)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 2.1.2)
      warden (~> 0.10.7)
    erubis (2.6.6)
      abstract (>= 1.0.0)
    factory_girl (1.3.2)
    factory_girl_rails (1.0)
      factory_girl (~> 1.3)
      rails (>= 3.0.0.beta4)
    faker (0.3.1)
    ffi (0.6.3)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
    geokit (1.5.0)
    haml (3.0.16)
    hirb (0.3.2)
    hoe (2.6.1)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rubyforge (>= 2.0.4)
    hpricot (0.8.2)
    i18n (0.4.1)
    json (1.4.6)
 json_pure (1.4.6)
    launchy (0.3.7)
      configuration (>= 0.0.5)
      rake (>= 0.8.1)
    libxml-ruby (1.1.4)
    linecache (0.43)
    mail (2.2.5)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.6)
      mime-types
      treetop (>= 1.4.5)
    mime-types (1.16)
    nokogiri (1.4.3.1)
    paperclip (2.3.3)
      activerecord
      activesupport
    polyglot (0.3.1)
    populator (0.2.5)
    rack (1.2.1)
    rack-mount (0.6.9)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-test (0.5.4)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.0.0.rc)
      actionmailer (= 3.0.0.rc)
      actionpack (= 3.0.0.rc)
      activerecord (= 3.0.0.rc)
      activeresource (= 3.0.0.rc)
      activesupport (= 3.0.0.rc)
      bundler (>= 1.0.0.rc.1)
      railties (= 3.0.0.rc)
    railties (3.0.0.rc)
      actionpack (= 3.0.0.rc)
      activesupport (= 3.0.0.rc)
      rake (>= 0.8.3)
      thor (~> 0.14.0)
 rake (0.8.7)
    roo (1.3.11)
      GData (>= 0.0.4)
      hpricot (>= 0.6)
      libxml-ruby (>= 1.1.3)
      rubyzip (>= 0.9.1)
      spreadsheet (>= 0.6.4)
    ruby-debug (0.10.3)
      columnize (>= 0.1)
      ruby-debug-base (~> 0.10.3.0)
    ruby-debug-base (0.10.3)
      linecache (>= 0.3)
    ruby-ole (1.2.10.1)
    rubyforge (2.0.4)
      json_pure (>= 1.1.7)
    rubyzip (0.9.4)
    selenium-webdriver (0.0.27)
      ffi (>= 0.6.1)
      json_pure
      rubyzip
    shoulda (2.11.0)
    spork (0.8.4)
    spreadsheet (0.6.4.1)
      ruby-ole
    sqlite3-ruby (1.3.1)
    thor (0.14.0)
    treetop (1.4.8)
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.22)
    warden (0.10.7)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    will_paginate (3.0.pre)
    wirble (0.1.3)
PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  capybara
  chronic
  crummy
  database_cleaner
  devise (= 1.1.rc2)
  factory_girl_rails
  faker
  geokit
  haml
  hirb
  hpricot
  json
  launchy
  paperclip
  populator
  rails (= 3.0.0.rc)
  roo (= 1.3.11)
  ruby-debug
  shoulda (= 2.11)
  spork
  sqlite3-ruby
  will_paginate (= 3.0.pre)
  wirble
```

Answer (score 24):

If you accidentally type `bundle install SOME_GEM` it seems to permanently set your gem directory to SOME_GEM.

Looks like you can get back to normal with `bundle install --system`

*command-line-ui-fail*

Figured out from: http://www.theirishpenguin.com/2011/03/05/bundler-installing-gems-into-the-wrong-directory-mea-culpa/

Comment: I don't understand why bundler wouldn't just use your current rvm directory? Any reason why it's not smart enough to know you are using this rvm gemset and it should install under that?

Answer (score 13):

Hmm.. just guessing that somehow when you originally installed bundler to. Try a reinstall with this :

> You can specify this setting when installing via `bundle install /path/to/bundle`. Bundler will remember where you installed the dependencies to on a particular machine for future installs, loads, setups, etc.

Also this is Carl Huda's recommendations for troubleshooting :

```
rm -rf ~/.bundle/ ~/.gem/ .bundle/ Gemfile.lock
bundle install
```

Comment: This worked for me. In case it helps anyone, I think I triggered this at some point by sleepily entering `bundle install coffee-script`

Comment: Just removing .bundle worked for me. I don't think you need to remove Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 4):

you've probably got BUNDLE_PATH: set in .bundle/config .  Change or remove that line.

Comment: +1 This is what happens if you do a `bundle install --system` as @Brian suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue after I upgraded Xcode

I had to run:
    sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
then: 
   sudo bundle install --system

After that everything was fine.