# Could not find rake-10.1.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, passenger, ubuntu-13.10

I have been working with rails and have been trying to setup passenger with rake 10.1.0 and it sends back me this errors.

Here is the link to the error.[Website LInk](http://brandtandlaura.com)

```
It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. This is probably because your
application is being run under a different environment than it's supposed to.
Please check the following:

 * Is this app supposed to be run as the `rails` user?
 * Is this app being run on the correct Ruby interpreter? Below you will
   see which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger attempted to use.
 * Are you using RVM? Please check whether the correct gemset is being used.
 * If all of the above fails, try resetting your RVM gemsets:
   https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Resetting-RVM-gemsets

-------- The exception is as follows: -------
Could not find rake-10.1.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs_for'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:148:in `requested_specs'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
  /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:219:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:333:in `running_bundler'
  /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:217:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:96:in `preload_app'
  /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:150:in `<module:App>'
  /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
Application root
/home/rails/testourwedding
Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV and PASSENGER_ENV)
production
Ruby interpreter command
/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/ruby
User and groups
uid=1000(rails) gid=1000(rails) groups=1000(rails),0(root),27(sudo),1001(rvm)
Environment variables
APACHE_PID_FILE = /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
rvm_bin_path = /usr/local/rvm/bin
GEM_HOME = /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global
APACHE_RUN_USER = www-data
SHELL = /bin/bash
IRBRC = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/.irbrc
PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1
PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR = /tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.XXXXcwNYKJ
SERVER_PORT = 80
MY_RUBY_HOME = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353
USER = rails
DOCUMENT_ROOT = /home/rails/testourwedding/public
_system_type = Linux
REQUEST_URI = /
rvm_path = /usr/local/rvm
IN_PASSENGER = 1
RACK_ENV = production
REMOTE_PORT = 53796
rvm_prefix = /usr/local
PATH = /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
APACHE_LOG_DIR = /var/log/apache2
WSGI_ENV = production
SERVER_ADMIN = [no address given]
PWD = /home/rails/testourwedding
LANG = C
APACHE_RUN_GROUP = www-data
NODE_PATH = /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/node_lib
_system_arch = x86_64
NODE_ENV = production
_system_version = 13.10
rvm_env_string = ruby-2.0.0-p353@global
REMOTE_ADDR = 72.32.146.52
rvm_version = 1.24.7 (stable)
SERVER_NAME = www.brandtandlaura.com
HOME = /home/rails
SHLVL = 0
rvm_gemset_name = global
RAILS_ENV = production
rvm_ruby_string = ruby-2.0.0-p353
SERVER_SOFTWARE = Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu)
LOGNAME = rails
QUERY_STRING = 
SERVER_ADDR = 166.78.174.208
GEM_PATH = /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global
SERVER_PROTOCOL = HTTP/1.1
PASSENGER_APP_ENV = production
APACHE_RUN_DIR = /var/run/apache2
APACHE_LOCK_DIR = /var/lock/apache2
REQUEST_METHOD = GET
RUBY_VERSION = ruby-2.0.0-p353
_system_name = Ubuntu
_ORIGINAL_GEM_PATH = /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global
Ulimits
Unknown
System memory usage
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          4001       1870       2131          0        180       1488
-/+ buffers/cache:        202       3799
Swap:            0          0          0
General Ruby interpreter information
RUBY_VERSION = 2.0.0
RUBY_PLATFORM = x86_64-linux
RUBY_ENGINE = ruby
RubyGems version = 2.1.11
Ruby configuration (RbConfig::CONFIG)
DESTDIR = 
MAJOR = 2
MINOR = 0
TEENY = 0
PATCHLEVEL = 353
INSTALL = /usr/bin/install -c
EXEEXT = 
prefix = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353
ruby_install_name = ruby
RUBY_INSTALL_NAME = ruby
RUBY_SO_NAME = ruby
exec = exec
ruby_pc = ruby-2.0.pc
PACKAGE = ruby
BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS =  newline.c
USE_RUBYGEMS = YES
MANTYPE = doc
NROFF = /usr/bin/nroff
vendorarchhdrdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/include/ruby-2.0.0/vendor_ruby/x86_64-linux
sitearchhdrdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/include/ruby-2.0.0/site_ruby/x86_64-linux
rubyarchhdrdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/include/ruby-2.0.0/x86_64-linux
vendorhdrdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/include/ruby-2.0.0/vendor_ruby
sitehdrdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/include/ruby-2.0.0/site_ruby
rubyhdrdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/include/ruby-2.0.0
UNIVERSAL_INTS = 
UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES = 
configure_args =  '--prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353' '--disable-install-doc' '--enable-shared'
vendorarchdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux
vendorlibdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0
vendordir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
sitearchdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux
sitelibdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0
sitedir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby
rubyarchdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux
rubylibdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0
ruby_version = 2.0.0
sitearch = x86_64-linux
arch = x86_64-linux
sitearchincludedir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/include/x86_64-linux
archincludedir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/include/x86_64-linux
sitearchlibdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/x86_64-linux
archlibdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/x86_64-linux
RI_BASE_NAME = ri
ridir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/share/ri
rubysitearchprefix = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/x86_64-linux
rubyarchprefix = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/x86_64-linux
rubylibprefix = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby
MAKEFILES = Makefile
PLATFORM_DIR = 
THREAD_MODEL = pthread
SYMBOL_PREFIX = 
EXPORT_PREFIX = 
COMMON_HEADERS = 
COMMON_MACROS = 
COMMON_LIBS = 
MAINLIBS = 
ENABLE_SHARED = yes
DLDLIBS =  -lc
SOLIBS = -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm 
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED = -Wl,-R -Wl,/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib -L/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib -lruby
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC = -Wl,-R -Wl,/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib -L/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib -lruby-static
LIBRUBYARG = -Wl,-R -Wl,/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib -L/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib -lruby
LIBRUBY = libruby.so.2.0.0
LIBRUBY_ALIASES = libruby.so.2.0 libruby.so
LIBRUBY_SO = libruby.so.2.0.0
LIBRUBY_A = libruby-static.a
RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME = 
rubyw_install_name = 
LIBRUBY_DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-soname,libruby.so.2.0 
LIBRUBY_LDSHARED = gcc -shared
EXTDLDFLAGS = 
EXTLDFLAGS = 
strict_warnflags = -ansi -std=iso9899:199409
warnflags = -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
debugflags = -ggdb3
optflags = -O3 -fno-fast-math
cxxflags =  -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
cflags =  -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
cppflags = 
NULLCMD = :
DLNOBJ = dln.o
INSTALLDOC = nodoc
CAPITARGET = nodoc
RDOCTARGET = nodoc
DTRACE_GLOMMED_OBJ = 
DTRACE_OBJ = 
DTRACE_EXT = dmyh
EXECUTABLE_EXTS = 
ARCHFILE = 
LIBRUBY_RELATIVE = no
EXTOUT = .ext
RUNRUBY_COMMAND = $(MINIRUBY) $(srcdir)/tool/runruby.rb --extout=.ext $(RUNRUBYOPT)
PREP = miniruby
BTESTRUBY = $(MINIRUBY)
CROSS_COMPILING = no
TEST_RUNNABLE = yes
setup = Setup
EXTSTATIC = 
STRIP = strip -S -x
TRY_LINK = 
LIBPATHENV = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
RPATHFLAG =  -Wl,-R%1$-s
LIBPATHFLAG =  -L%1$-s
LINK_SO = 
LIBEXT = a
DLEXT2 = 
DLEXT = so
LDSHAREDXX = g++ -shared
LDSHARED = gcc -shared
CCDLFLAGS = -fPIC
STATIC = 
ARCH_FLAG = 
DLDFLAGS = 
ALLOCA = 
codesign = 
POSTLINK = :
WERRORFLAG = -Werror
CHDIR = cd -P
RMALL = rm -fr
RMDIRS = rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty -p
RMDIR = rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty
CP = cp
RM = rm -f
PKG_CONFIG = pkg-config
PYTHON = 
DOXYGEN = 
DOT = 
DTRACE = 
MAKEDIRS = /bin/mkdir -p
MKDIR_P = /bin/mkdir -p
INSTALL_DATA = /usr/bin/install -c -m 644
INSTALL_SCRIPT = /usr/bin/install -c
INSTALL_PROGRAM = /usr/bin/install -c
SET_MAKE = 
LN_S = ln -s
NM = nm
DLLWRAP = 
WINDRES = 
OBJCOPY = :
OBJDUMP = objdump
ASFLAGS = 
AS = as
AR = ar
RANLIB = ranlib
try_header = 
COUTFLAG = -o 
OUTFLAG = -o 
CPPOUTFILE = -o conftest.i
GNU_LD = yes
LD = ld
GCC = yes
EGREP = /bin/grep -E
GREP = /bin/grep
CPP = gcc -E
CXXFLAGS =  -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
CXX = g++
OBJEXT = o
CPPFLAGS =   
LDFLAGS = -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic
CFLAGS =  -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC
CC = gcc
NACL_SDK_VARIANT = 
NACL_SDK_ROOT = 
NACL_TOOLCHAIN = 
target_os = linux
target_vendor = unknown
target_cpu = x86_64
target = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
host_os = linux-gnu
host_vendor = unknown
host_cpu = x86_64
host = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
RUBY_VERSION_NAME = ruby-2.0.0
RUBYW_BASE_NAME = rubyw
RUBY_BASE_NAME = ruby
build_os = linux-gnu
build_vendor = unknown
build_cpu = x86_64
build = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
RUBY_RELEASE_DATE = 2013-11-22
RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION = 2.0.0
target_alias = 
host_alias = 
build_alias = 
LIBS = -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm 
ECHO_T = 
ECHO_N = -n
ECHO_C = 
DEFS = 
mandir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/share/man
localedir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/share/locale
libdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib
psdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/share/doc/ruby
pdfdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/share/doc/ruby
dvidir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/share/doc/ruby
htmldir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/share/doc/ruby
infodir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/share/info
docdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/share/doc/ruby
oldincludedir = /usr/include
includedir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/include
localstatedir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/var
sharedstatedir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/com
sysconfdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/etc
datadir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/share
datarootdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/share
libexecdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/libexec
sbindir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/sbin
bindir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin
exec_prefix = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353
PACKAGE_URL = 
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT = 
PACKAGE_STRING = 
PACKAGE_VERSION = 
PACKAGE_TARNAME = 
PACKAGE_NAME = 
PATH_SEPARATOR = :
SHELL = /bin/bash
archdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux
topdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux
Activated Ruby gems
bundler => 1.3.5
Ruby load path ($LOAD_PATH)
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux
Ruby loaded libraries ($LOADED_FEATURES)
enumerator.so
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/errors.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/version.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/platform.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/thread.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tmpdir.rb
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpio.rb
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/operating_system.rb
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/ruby.rb
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/binary_compatibility.rb
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/buildout/ruby/ruby-2.0.0-x86_64-linux/passenger_native_support.so
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/socket.so
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/socket.rb
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_enhancements.rb
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpdir.rb
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/public_api.rb
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/debug_logging.rb
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/fcntl.so
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/constants.rb
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/message_channel.rb
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/message_client.rb
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/unseekable_socket.rb
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/stringio.so
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/tee_input.rb
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb
/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/lib/phusion_passenger/analytics_logger.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/path_support.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/pathname.so
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pathname.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/gem_path_manipulation.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/gem_helpers.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/match_platform.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/version.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/settings.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/digest.so
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/digest.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/digest/sha1.so
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/set.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/dependency.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/ruby_dsl.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/dsl.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ftp.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/http.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/https.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ldap.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ldaps.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/mailto.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/zlib.so
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/exceptions.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/header.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/generic_request.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/request.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/requests.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/responses.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/proxy_delta.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/backward.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/date_core.so
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/date/format.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/date.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/time.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/request.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/core.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/util.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/cookie.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/uri_formatter.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/bn.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/cipher.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/config.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/digest.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/x509.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/buffering.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/ssl.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/securerandom.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/resolv.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/text.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/name_tuple.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/strscan.so
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/path.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/git.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/forwardable.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/index.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/remote_specification.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/endpoint_specification.rb
```

Please provide questions. Thanks for the help. I will update this question with a better one because I don't know how to ask it.

Here is the gemset for that RVM path

```
rails@are-wedding:~$ rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p353@global
Using /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353 with gemset global
rails@are-wedding:~$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.0)
bundler (1.3.5)
daemon_controller (1.1.7)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
minitest (4.3.2)
passenger (4.0.27)
psych (2.0.0)
rack (1.5.2)
rake (10.1.0, 0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
```

I have asked a lot of people but I feel this problem is something to do with RVM. Anyway any help.

```
rake --version    
rake, version 10.1.0
```

Here is the configuration information in the */etc/apache2/apache2.conf*

```
   LoadModule passenger_module /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.27
   PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/ruby
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have some basic gems set up on your host...  Can you connect to the remote machine and install gems?

Comment: Based on the above, it looks like the only gem installed is `bundler`...

Comment: Yes, it seems the gems are not installed. Do you use Apache or Nginx? The host configuration file could help find the issue too. Be careful to reveal that configuration if that is a production system.

Comment: Yes your right it is not installed However according to that gem set it is installed.

Comment: It looks like your app muddles up your `rake` gems. Would you try `gem uninstall rake --version 0.9.6`? BTW, what’s the output of `rake --version`?

Comment: rails@are-wedding:~$ rake --version

  rake, version 10.1.0

Comment: Well it is using apache with passenger. Incase anyone wanted to know.

Comment: Where exactly is your `rake` gem? Is it in `/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/rake-10.1.0` or in `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/rake-10.1.0`? Which one?

Comment: The rake file is in the `/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems` folder.

Comment: Ah I see the problem. /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems is not in your gem path! Add it, and you should be fine.

Comment: Oh sweet thanks I will try that out when I get a chance and see if it works. I will respond back with what I did to fix it.

Answer (score 13):

Your problem is that you added an additional gem that has unresolved dependencies. Run `bundle update` to update your dependencies and you should be good to go.

Comment: That would be correct however that is not what the error is saying also there is no Gemfile. This gemset is built for one reason and one reason only. To server as my gemset for capistrano and passenger.

Comment: Are you sure there is no Gemfile? The error message clearly states that Phusion Passenger was trying to activate Bundler. It only does that if you do have a Gemfile.

Comment: Ok that is true the application does have a gem file however the global gemset done not have a gem file. Also I do have that gem installed so even if what your saying would fix it which I have tried by the way it still does not explain why I can't find the gem in the global gemset even when it very clearly say in the global gemset that the rake 10.1.0 is installed. Thanks for the try but this is not helping.

Comment: yep then you get some freakiness from the precomiplers as sprockets is f**ked up

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that when you run the ruby command from the web server, it does not add `/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems` to your `GEM_PATH`, only `/usr/local/rvm/.../gems`. Your rake gem is installed in `/home/rails/.rvm/gems`. You need to add `/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems` to `GEM_PATH`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it is exactly what got me looking in the right direction. After which I found the solution to changing the gemset path.

Comment: could someone explain how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

So after hours of working on this problem I found what it was created by. So here is how I solved it.

First problem was with the fact that I installed rvm incorrectly. I installed it under the rails user which resulted in some access problems. However this does not resolve the problem with the can't find the rake file. In order to fix this I had to start over. Because it was a cloud server starting over was easy. Just did a full rest and followed there few steps.

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install build-essential

rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p353
rvm ruby-2.0.0-p353@global --default --create
gem install passenger
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Not all these steps are needed on some server depending on what is installed but in my case I wanted to make sure everything worked.

As you run the last command `passenger-install-apache2-module` you will see something like this. Just follow the instructions in my case I got this result.

```
Installation instructions for required software

 * To install Curl development headers with SSL support:
   Please run apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev or libcurl4-gnutls-dev, whichever you prefer.

 * To install Apache 2:
   Please install it with apt-get install apache2-mpm-worker

 * To install Apache 2 development headers:
   Please install it with apt-get install apache2-threaded-dev

 * To install Apache Portable Runtime (APR) development headers:
   Please install it with apt-get install libapr1-dev

 * To install Apache Portable Runtime Utility (APU) development headers:
   Please install it with apt-get install libaprutil1-dev
```

This was simple just followed the install steps and now I have apache running. After that you just run `passenger-install-apache2-module` again.

Everything should pass this time and we are on to the next step.

In my case the next step was to add this code to the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

```
   LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.29/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.29
   PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/ruby
```

I just added it to the top really does not matter where you add it everything works.

after you have done that make a new ruby on rails application with these steps

```
rvm use rvm ruby-2.0.0-p353@test --create
gem install rails
gem install bundler
rails new tester
cd tester
```

After which you need to create a new sites-avaliable.Mine looks like this.

```
root@rails-app:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.conf
   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName www.something.com
      # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
      DocumentRoot /home/rails/apps/tester/public
      <Directory "/home/rails/apps/tester/public">
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
         AllowOverride all
         # MultiViews must be turned off.
         Options -MultiViews
     Require all granted
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

Run this to restart and add test

```
sudo a2ensite test && sudo service apache2 restart
```

Found out that if you don't have the `Require all granted` it will send you a error message that looks something like this in the error log. Not total sure if you need any of the others like `Allow from all` but I added them anyway. Here is some extra documentation on this error if you want some more reading [Wiki Apache Org](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration)

```
[client 75.1.169.97:51729] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/rails/apps/tester/public/
```

oh if you were wondering the error log is located in `/var/log/apache2/`

**After which it got me back to the error I noted above**

So here is how I fixed can't find the `Could not find rake-10.1.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`.

first thing you need to do is simple just created `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` here is what mine look like.

```
rails@rails-app:~/apps/tester$ cat .ruby-version
ruby-2.0.0-p353
rails@rails-app:~/apps/tester$ cat .ruby-gemset
test
```

after that you need to add this file into your config folder

```
# config/setup_load_paths.rb
 if ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'] && ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'].include?('rvm')
  begin
    rvm_path     = File.dirname(File.dirname(ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME']))
    rvm_lib_path = File.join(rvm_path, 'lib')
    # $LOAD_PATH.unshift rvm_lib_path
    require 'rvm'
    RVM.use_from_path! File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__))
  rescue LoadError
    # RVM is unavailable at this point.
    raise "RVM ruby lib is currently unavailable."
  end
end

ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = File.expand_path('../Gemfile', File.dirname(__FILE__))
require 'bundler/setup'
```

This is a bit of magic here but was it is doing is changing the default rvm gemset for passenger. However if your using capistrano you can use rvm-capistrano. However you have to use older version of capistrano. Capistrano 3 does not work with rvm-capistrano.

If this does not work for you might be how you have it set up. Anyway hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact Passenger message and resolved it with this solution from Brian Armstrong: [Bundler installing gems in wrong location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459412/bundler-installing-gems-in-wrong-location)
(run bundle install --system).

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot more hassle than needbe. All you really had to do was reset your gemsets: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Resetting-RVM-gemsets

rvm gemset empty

or before rvm use whateveryourgemset

Basically you can list all active gemsets, empty them all, then install passenger into the correct one by installing your bundle again from the application folder. Problem solved.